# Train a huge model inception with keras

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I need to train an inception model with more than 400 000 images.

I know I can't load it all on the memory, since it's too big.
So, I will certainly train it over batch, instead than epoch (And so generate load every batch from the disk)
But, it will be very slow, no ?

Do you know if there is a different way of doing it ?

I also want to apply different and aleatory transformations to my images during the training.
I looked over the dataimagegenerator class, but, it's incompatible with all the images I have.
So, there is a way to do that without the generator ?

Thanks to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `fit_generator` method (https://keras.io/models/model/#fit_generator) of the model. This still loads images from memory, however this is done in parallel and has less overhead. You can write your own generator to apply the transformations you want to (https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

If you need faster memory access you can take a look at hdf5. You can store the images in hdf5 to provide faster indexing and loading for your program. (http://www.h5py.org/)